# git source control provider gitignore and ms-persist.xml issue

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

When i create a project and use git source control provider and then exclude some paths/files it creates a file ms-persist.xml in the .git directory to keep record of these actions.

I do not see any information from these dir/file excludes in my gitignore.

The problem is that when i push to the git repository the ms-persist.xml which is placed in the .git directory by visual studio does not get pushed.
Meaning when somebody else clones the project and opens the visual studio source control he has to re-select all directories and exclude them.

Is there a way to make this work with the gitignore file, or re-locate the ms-persist.xml so it comes with the project when cloned ?

Comment: removed the wrong tags; please add information on what IDE you're using (it seems you're using some sort of Microsoft IDE? is that right?)

Comment: Hi, yes : Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffc631e1-de5b-4fad-b173-b1f9318ef3fd/visual-studio-2013-and-gitignore?forum=visualstudiogeneral:

> We are using the standard nuget 2.7 that ships with vs2013.  We use it
>   to install libraries into our C++ projects.  Anyway, it turned out the
>   the issue can be resolved by shutting down visual studio, and then
>   deleting the ms-persist.xml file from the .git folder, and then
>   restarting visual studio.  After that, it seemed to honor the
>   .gitignore file, and stopped trying to add files from the /packages
>   folder into the git repository.  I'm guessing that the problem might
>   have been caused the the older git extension for Visual Studio 2012,
>   but stayed around because it was baked into that ms-persist file.

Comment: I attempted this but when i open up the project again, it just re-creates the ms-persist file in the .git directory.  When i exclude a directory, it gets added in the ms-persist file and not in the gitignore file.